# Allowing an element to dragged accross Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, interact.js

Goody day guys, i am trying create a page using bootstrap and interactjs, yes, I've heard about jQueryUI's draggable and droppable, but it's conflicts with the main jQuery file, is a bit annoying so i turned to interactjs, and it actually did what i wanted it to do per se, the problem is that i can't drag an element across two columns(sidebar to main panel), what happens when i try is that the element goes "Underneath" the other column/panel.[image: The arrow points at element i am trying to drag across]

The code that's responsible for moving the element
[image: onmove code]

This is the HTML code, the element starts at the element with the angular repeat directive (div... ng-repeat=...)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Drag-on IDE">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="Integrated Learning Object Development Environment">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

    <title>Drag-on IDE</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="LEQueryController">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><button class="btn btn-default btn-info">Upload a Learning Element</button></li>
            <li><button class="btn btn-default btn-success">Upload Material</button></li>
          </div>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" ng-submit="controller.query()">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search Learning Element..." type="text" ng-model="searchText">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      </nav>

  
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
      <!--SIDE BAR-->
          <div class="sidebar col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <div class="list-group nav nav-sidebar" >
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item draggable" ng-repeat="result in results">
                <span class="badge">{{result.type}}</span>
                <span class="badge">{{result.size}}</span>
                <h4>
                  {{result.title}}
                  <br /><small>{{result.author}}</small>
                  <br /><small>{{result.publishingDate}}</small>
                </h4>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </div>
        
      </div>
      <!--SIDE BAR END-->
        
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 main">
        <div class="container" id="lo-workspace">
          <div class="draggable jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>Drag-on IDE <small>by Team Akura</small></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Drag-on IDE <small>by Team Akura</small></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Drag-on IDE <small>by Team Akura</small></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Drag-on IDE <small>by Team Akura</small></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Drag-on IDE <small>by Team Akura</small></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Drag-on IDE <small>by Team Akura</small></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Drag-on IDE <small>by Team Akura</small></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--
      *******  *******  *****    *******
         *     *     *  *    *   *     *
         *     *     *  *     *  *     *
         *     *     *  *    *   *     *
         *     *******  *****    *******
          TO : Alfonso
          Draggable mechanism is acting like a *, 
          complaining something like "$(...).draggable isn't a function because i'm having my period today".
    -->
  
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/interact.js/interact.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="utilities.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>
    
    
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

What causes this problem? how do i fix it? thanks.

Comment: Please replace all of the images with code.

Comment: How do jQuery UI and jQuery conflict? They are supposed to work together...